# Joining of two table on a column which includes null value

Tags: mysql

I have two table Table-A and Table-B as given in picture.I want to join Table-A and Table-B on the column UIN.In table-A some records in column UIN contains null value. I want to include those records.My output should look like Table-C.I tried it by join these table  but it does not including the receord which have null value of UIN in Table-A. Can any one help me out
[Click here for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alARu.jpg)

Comment: always  post what u have try(code) in question.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] - That is a screenshot from excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either use full outer join or left join, depending on what you want to do when there are ids in Table B which are not present in Table A

```
select *
from A full outer join B
on A.UIN = B.UIN
```

or

```
select *
from A left join B
on A.UIN = B.UIN
```